# How to add a search feature to a static site using Nuxt.js and Nuxt Content headless CMS

Tags: nuxt.js, content-management-system, nuxt-content

I built a blog website using Nuxt.js static site generation and the Nuxt Content headless CMS module. I'm now trying to build a search page where the user can input various queries for filtering articles, e.g. title, fulltext, author, date published etc.

Is that possible on a static site? Or do I have to host the CMS separately and make dynamic requests in order for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static site is "static" because of the files that you do have at the end. It's not static in the meaning that you cannot use JS.

You can totally use a [`.filter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) if you have your data locally somewhere in your `data` or alike, otherwise you could probably reach out for the [`.search` method of the module](https://content.nuxtjs.org/snippets#search).

Comment: How do I know if/where my content data is stored locally? If a browser makes a request to the CDN with the static site, is all the content downloaded on the first request? Or can I make dynamic requests to the CDN later? How does this work exactly?

Comment: @DaDo your nuxt content should be available in your final bundle. The fastest way of checking this is still to implement a quick search and see how it goes. Also, you can check your built bundle into the `/dist` directory. [Nuxt content](https://content.nuxtjs.org/) is not a hosted CMS, but one that keeps your data locally AFAIK. So, if you're using it, you may have your `.md` or alike already in your project (if we're talking about the same module). In case of a remote headless CMS, yeah you could totally fetch the content with an axios request or so.